# how to load a file into pig with multiple delimiter?

Tags: python, apache-pig, hadoop-streaming

I have below file `tax_cal` I want to load in pig:

> 101,5|2;3|2
>
> 102,3|1;4.5|2;4|1
>
> 103,2|1;5|2;5.6|3

output:

> 101,5|2,3|2
>
> 102,3|1,4.5|2,4|1
>
> 103,2|1,5|2,5.6|3

Further, I will pass this output file to a python UDF to calculate totalprice.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you add the first line of your file, which you need to load using pig

Comment: sorry i didn't get you?

Answer (score 1):

So the basic load command for pig is as below, but I am not sure with your file sample data type. Try to look at this below and check if you can modify it the way you needed.

```
    A = LOAD '(your_file_name)' USING PigStorage(',') AS (bill_number:INT, tax:chararray);
```

Comment: No doing this will only give me value after '|' , i got below output:(,2;3)
(,2;4)
(,2;2.5)  i don't know how to separate this file :(

Comment: Well I dont understand your text file, please post first 5 lines of your text file

Comment: Hi, this is the file which i want to load to explain it first column is bill number :int and second column is array having tax_details. for example 5|2 where 5 id price and 2 is tax. i have to load this file in pig and then pass it through UDF to calculate total price.

Comment: so is it separated by tab's or commas

Comment: Assuming its comma separated I will be editing the above answer of mine, for bill number and tax

Comment: it is seperated by comma's

Comment: no by doing PigStorage(',') it will not solve the issue , since  it will stop when it see first comma and truncate other so output will be :101,5|2

102,3|1

103,2|1

Comment: I understand that you need 101 as bill number and  5 is tax, then again 102 as tax and 3 as bill number ? Is this right ?

Comment: Hi, I did below steps and it worked but facing different problem:
A = load 'tax_cal' using PigStorage(' ') as (bill_no:int,tax_details:chararray);  
B = FOREACH A GENERATE bill_no,FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(tax_details,',')) AS letter; 
REGISTER 'tax_calulator.py' USING jython as newudf            
C = FOREACH B GENERATE bill_no, letter , newudf.price(letter);
D = group C by (bill_no,totalprice);    
E = foreach D generate FLATTEN(group) as (bill_no,totalprice), SUM(C.totalprice) as sum1;

Comment: on dumping E it give:
(101,9.0,9.0)
(101,16.5,16.5)
(102,8.0,8.0)
(102,10.0,10.0)
(102,10.5,10.5)
(103,7.5,7.5)
(103,18.0,18.0)

but i wanted sum for each bill_no like 101, 25.5.... can you help me in this please?

Comment: while applying foreach just do the regular sum method over bill_no